# How to extend es6 child class functions parameters?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jsdoc

I want override jsdoc for function which inheritance from base class.

the function adds parameter to base function.

parent:

```
export default class Base {
    /**
     * Function apply().
     *
     * Apply the hook.
     *
     * @param {{}} args
     *
     * @returns {Boolean}
     */
    apply( args ) {
        throw Error( 'apply() must be implanted.' );
    }
}
```

child:

```
export default class Child extends Base {
    /**
     * how to override jsdoc and point out that i
     * have added containers param?
     */
    apply( args, containers ) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@override tag will be useful i think. https://jsdoc.app/tags-override.html for reference